# How do you trick SAX into breaking large chunks into smaller chunks in java?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am overriding

```
public void characters(char[] ch,
                       int start,
                       int length)
                throws SAXException
```

when parsing an XML document.  It works perfectly for small XML documents (1MB or less).  However, if the XML document is 100MB or more) I start getting java heap space out of memory errors inside this function.

After doing a bit of research [here](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#endElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) I realized the size of the character array "ch" above depends on how many characters are in between "startElement()" and "endElement()" .

So I'm wondering, would there be a smart way to override "startElement" and "endElement" to return a smaller data chunk?

For example, suppose I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<element1>
   This is a very simple sentence that is not very long. 
</element1>
```

Currently the "characters()" function would return "This is a very simple sentence that is not very long." as a chunk.

But my problem is what if the XML file looks like:

```
<element1>
   An entire book's worth of content is pasted in this single element. Possibly millions of characters.  
</element1>
```

Is there a way I can "trick" startElement() and endElement() to have the characters() function return chunks of the book insead of the whole book?

Comment: 100 MiB is not that much... Care to show your code?

Comment: actually, i thought the java sax parser already did that by default?

Comment: are you using the standard java parser, or some third-party implementation?

Comment: The issue here is unlikely to be the SAX parser configuration, it's a lot more likely to be that the characters method implementation is inadequate. The OP doesn't demonstrate any awareness of how to use the characters method correctly, and doesn't include a [mcve]. Voting to close as OffTopic/no mcve.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *trick* a SAX parser into feeding character data to your `ContentHandler` in smaller chunks.  Parsers are already permitted to feed it in chunks smaller than the whole content of an element, however, and I would expect that to be their normal behavior when the content is large.  Doing otherwise would require them to buffer a potentially large amount of data internally, for no particular reason.

If you find that your particular parser is indeed delivering larger chunks than you would like, then you should consult its documentation.  There could be an option you could set to influence that.  Otherwise, your alternative is to find or make a parser whose behavior you like better.

However, do check your facts.  It may be that the parser is indeed returning the data in reasonable-size chunks, and the problem is really in what you're doing with them.  In particular, if you are building some kind of in-memory representation of the whole file, then it hardly matters in what size pieces you receive it.

Also consider increasing the VM's maximum heap size.  A 100MB file is not outrageously large, but your VM could be hobbled by a heap size limit that's unrealistically low for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread but recently i had to deal with similar task, So posting my answer it can be useful to some others. Lates java version i think jdk 9 has the feature to read chunks of character data, you just need to set the CDATA_CHUNK_SIZE, Its available in both Stax and Sax parsers.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class SaxDemo {

    final static String CDATA_CHUNK_SIZE = "jdk.xml.cdataChunkSize";

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(new TestHandler());

            try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("FileDir/file")) {

                reader.setProperty(CDATA_CHUNK_SIZE, 10000);

                reader.parse(new InputSource(is));
                System.out.println("Done");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```